# Jquery.on('click') not working when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of li elements on which I've binded a function so they could work as buttons, this do work but when I scroll down a bit you can still click them but nothing happens.

I bind the function with the $.on() function as follows

```
$(".class").off();
$(".class").on('click', function(){
    alert("something happens!");
});
```

This problem only occurs in firefox (version 18.0) has anyone seen this behavior before, or knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

J.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com or whatever) so that we can test it ?

Comment: Perhaps you have an invisible element positioned at `top:100%`?

Comment: check the answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "on" with document and it should work fine :

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(){
    alert("something happens!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try `.on()` in this manner:

```
$("body").on('click', ".class", function(){
   alert("something happens!");
});
```

Comment: I suggest `$(document).on(...` instead of `$("body").on(...`. However, static binding might not be the cause.